# When can your reaction be used?

Tags: dnd-5e, counterspelling

I have an argument with my players every once in a while and it is always the same sincero.

Character 1- I cast fireball

Character 2- I cast counterspell

Character 1- Well I counterspell your counterspell so my fireball goes off

As the DM I never know if "Character 1" can actually do this. So is this possible?

Comment: Which question are you *actually* asking? *"When can your reaction be used?"* or *"is this scenario possible?"*? Please make it clear what you're actually asking.